# Array assigned statically does not overflow when assigning values out of range

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

Why does this code work?
I  have an array of 2 elements and it should overflow, but it does not even give me an error on Linux using gcc. Instead, it works and outputs 5.

```
int doS(int a[2])
{

printf("%d", a[4]);

}

int main()

{


int rows =2;

int a[rows];

a[0] = 1;
a[1] = 2;
a[2]= 3;
a[3] = 4;
a[4] = 5;

doS(a);
}
```

Comment: This means you are under the dark magic of undefined behavior! Reading about it will break the spell.

Comment: *"Why does this code work?"* - It doesn't. You were lulled into the false sense that it does simply because it appears to do so. You're confusing *defined* behavior with *observed* behavior. The latter doesn't necessarily equate to the former, but the former will reliably lead to the later.

Comment: Because what happens when you trigger Undefined Behavior is undefined. Your harddrive getting formatted is a valid result too.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that it always works! `a[2]`, `a[3]` and `a[4]` are out of memory. Behaviour of the code is called as *[Undefined Behaviour](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Undefined_behavior)*

For example, try below one. Does it still work?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        a[i] = i + 1;
}
```